# Calling a function inside the same class objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am new to Objective C and I couldn t find resources on this subject at all

let s say I have a function Called A and a function called B , both belong to the same Class , how should I call function B inside of function A ? assuming they both belong to a Class called C

Thanks

Comment: A "function" is not the same as a "method".

Answer (score 5):

```
//other code inside your project

-(void) functionA
{
NSLog(@"Hello"); // not sure if the syntax for this is right, but it should be

}

-(void) functionB
{
[self functionA];
}
```

Comment: Even if this solves your problem, I strongly recommend you learn some more about objective c before trying to make anything...

Answer (score 3):

call `[self B]` in A.

This would be a good start: http://cocoadevcentral.com/

Comment: This http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/ObjC.pdf will be a much better place to start

Answer (score 2):

[Objective C has methods rather than functions, though it does support C functions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846825/c-function-vs-objective-c-method) To call a method called B inside the current class, you send a message to the current instance of the class, i.e. "self", calling its method B:

```
[self B];
```

This presumes that the method B is defined:

```
-(void) B {
// Whatever method B does, it does not require any parameters.
}
```